# sshtunnel not working in when used in a function

Tags: python, database, pandas, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create a sshtunnel to access my database. I am using the sshtunnel package together with SQLalchemy and pandas.

**Example 1**

```
# run in terminal
ssh -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 [ssh_config]    

# run in iPython
pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

When I create an ssh tunnel on my terminal and then run the query with pandas (see example above), it works fine and the DataFrame is returned.

**Example 2**

When I create the tunnel and then generate a connection in that context, it does not work.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    os.environ['SSH_ADDRESS'], 
    ssh_username=os.environ['SSH_USER'],
    ssh_pkey=os.environ['SSH_PKEY'],
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 5433)
) as sshserver:
    conn = self.engine.connect()
    pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()
    sshserver.stop()
```

The error message is:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
[SQL: '\nselect \nid\n\nfrom \nclean.accounts \n\nlimit 10\n']
```

The really curious thing is that this problem 'alternates'. What I mean by this is that running it once will cause the error message to occur. But if I run the function again, it returns the Dataframe. And if I try running it a third time, the error message appears again. This goes on indefinitely each time I run the command.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I guess removing `sshserver.stop()` from last line will work for you.
When we are using `with` function to handle files or server connections; it itself take care of opening & closing the file or connection resp. There is no need to explicitly close the connection.

More description [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)